# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject randomly

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I am facing this problem randomly: I have a table with latitude,longitude and location type columns where location column is having geometry type and the data is entered correctly and also I am able to get data back sometime but sometime I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject

This is the relevant part of my class

```
    public List<Asset_Data> findMostRecentByAsset_ID(String device_address,
                Integer trail) {
            Query q2 = namedQuery("com.cliftonlabs.trakitdb.core.asset_data.findMostRecentByAsset_id");
            Session s = factory.getCurrentSession();
            String sql = q2.getQueryString();
            SQLQuery q = s.createSQLQuery(sql);
            q.setParameter("device_address", device_address);
            q.setParameter("trail", trail);
            q.addEntity(Asset_Data.class);
            q.setParameter("device_address", device_address);
            return list(q);
        }
    
        public List<Asset_Data> findMostRecentByAsset_IDList(
                List<String> device_address_list, 
                Integer trail,
                boolean queryGPSNullOnly) {
    
            String queryString = "";
            int n_assets = device_address_list.size();
    
            if (n_assets == 0) {
                // return early if we dont have anything to query
                return new ArrayList<Asset_Data>();
            }
            
            String gpsQuery = queryGPSNullOnly
                    ? " and longitude is null and latitude is null"
                    : " and longitude is not null and latitude is not null";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n_assets; i++) {
                queryString += "(select * from asset_data where device_address=:asset_"
                        + String.valueOf(i)
                        + gpsQuery
                        + " order by timestamp DESC limit :trail)";
    
                if (n_assets > 1) {
                    if (i < (device_address_list.size() - 1)) {
                        queryString += " UNION ";
                    } else {
                        queryString += " order by device_address";
                    }
                }
            }
    
            Session currentSession = currentSession();
            String tenant = currentSession.getTenantIdentifier();
            //Session session = null;
            List<Asset_Data> r;
            try{
                //session = this.factory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(tenant).openSession();
   
                currentSession.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
    
                Query query = currentSession.createSQLQuery(queryString).addEntity(Asset_Data.class);
                query.setParameter("trail", trail);
                for (int i = 0; i < device_address_list.size(); i++) {
                    query.setParameter("asset_" + String.valueOf(i),
                            device_address_list.get(i));
                }
                r = list(query);
            
            }finally {
                if(currentSession!=null)
                {
                    //session.close();
                    currentSession.flush();
                    currentSession.setDefaultReadOnly(false);
                }
            }
            return r;
        }
```

And this is the error I get

```
ERROR [2022-08-26 03:59:14,854] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 6a1e93a98391cc97
    ! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
    ! at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS(PGGeometryValueExtractor.java:113) ~[hibernate-spatial-4.3.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.doExtract(AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.java:50) ~[hibernate-spatial-4.3.jar:4.3.0.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ! at io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO.list(AbstractDAO.java:124) ~[classes/:na]
    ! at com.cliftonlabs.trakit_api_bundle.db.Asset_DataDAO.findMostRecentByAsset_IDList(Asset_DataDAO.java:165) ~[classes/:na]
    ! at com.cliftonlabs.trakit.appapi.resources.LiveResource.listMsgs(LiveResource.java:108) ~[classes/:na]
    ! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    ! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    ! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    ! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.codahale.metrics.jersey.InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TimedRequestDispatcher.dispatch(InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:30) ~[metrics-jersey-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ! at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkRequestDispatcher.dispatch(UnitOfWorkRequestDispatcher.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
    ! at io.dropwizard.jersey.guava.OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter$OptionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter.java:37) ~[dropwizard-jersey-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceObjectRule.accept(ResourceObjectRule.java:100) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) ~[jersey-server-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715) ~[jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
    ! at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
    ! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) ~[dropwizard-jetty-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1515) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83) ~[jetty-servlets-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:348) ~[jetty-servlets-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:127) ~[dropwizard-jetty-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) ~[dropwizard-servlets-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44) ~[dropwizard-jersey-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39) ~[dropwizard-jersey-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:248) ~[jetty-servlets-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:211) ~[jetty-servlets-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:519) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1097) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:448) ~[jetty-servlet-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175) ~[metrics-jetty9-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51) ~[dropwizard-jetty-0.7.1.jar:0.7.1]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:162) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:446) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:271) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
    ! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:246) ~[jetty-server-9.0.7.v20131107.jar:9.0.7.v20131107]
```

These are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cliftonlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>trakitng_app_api</artifactId>

    <version>1.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://git.cliftonlabs.com/trak-it/app-api.git</connection>
        <url>https://git.cliftonlabs.com/trak-it/app-api.git</url>
    </scm>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>https://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>https://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- VScode only -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cliftonlabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>trakit_api_bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../trakit-api-bundle/target/trakit_api_bundle-1.3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-spdy</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-views-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-views-mustache</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.178</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3m</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.geocoder-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>geocoder-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>0.6.2</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>3.4</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devlab722</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.federecio</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.44</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.7.v20131107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.7.v20131107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.7.v20131107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bendb.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>${amazon.aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>${amazon.aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${amazon.aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <dropwizard.version>0.7.1</dropwizard.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <amazon.aws.sdk.version>1.10.77</amazon.aws.sdk.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.cliftonlabs.trakit.appapi.AppApiApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> 
                <executions> <execution> <id>attach-javadocs</id> <goals> <goal>jar</goal> 
                </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>../trakit-api-bundle/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <shortRevisionLength>6</shortRevisionLength>
                    <format>{0}_{1,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>scmVersion</item>
                        <item>timestamp</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}_${buildNumber}</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>version.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>version.txt</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            build-helper-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.9.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong please.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a really, really old verson of Hibernate & Hibernate Spatial !  Also don't mix the postgis-jdbc and Hibernate Spatial. If you use Hibernate Spatial, you don't need postgis-jdbc.